# transport_carbon module not working in Jupyter despite successful instalation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

1)I use Jupyter and I just installed the module "transport_carbon" entering the following on the cmd:

```
pip install transport_carbon
```

2)When I get back to the Juypter notebook and try to import the modules I receive the following:

```
ImportError: No module named 'carbon'
```

3)After that I installed it again and I receive the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: transport_carbon in 
c:\mlandaverde\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

4) Finally I tried installing via conda:

```
conda install transport_carbon
```

here I got the answer "No package found in current win-64 channels matching: transport_carbon"

5) I also did the search by entering:

```
anaconda search -t conda transport_carbon
```

The answer was: "Found 0 packages"

Would this mean that I cannot use this module in Jupyter at all? If so what other options would I have?

Thanks in advance,

The python version is the following: Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)|
ML

Comment: check **which python** first

Comment: Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)|; thanks

Answer (score 1):

The library is not python >3 compatible.

If you wanted to make modifications to make it python 3  compatible, you are looking at making imports within the package relative.

For example, change the content of `__init__.py` to:

```
from .carbon import *
from .distance import *
```

You would also need to update the urllib api calls to python 3 compatible versions.

Then, you also need to install dependencies: `geopy`, `pygeocoder`, `requests`, etc.

You can install local directories with pip via 
`pip install -e <directory>`